# Stop Access from changing formatting of text field

Tags: ms-access

I have a .csv file that I am pasting in to an access table, and one of the fields is populated with the string "TRUE" in the .csv - Access 2013 is reformatting this as "-1" automatically which is not what I want. I know this is how Access stores a "TRUE" value by default, but I just want access treat the field as a string. I tried setting the column I am pasting this in to the data type "text" but it still changes "TRUE" to "-1".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you just doing this once, or is it something you will do in future using code? If just once you might switch to Datasheet View and just use the Replace option.

Comment: This is why I build my own import routines in VBA. I use the File System Object to open the file and then manually import each field, each row. This way you can build your own logic. You will also need to setup your table before importing, unless you're really handy with creating tables from code.